# Call to IBOutlet in custom UIView from another class

Tags: swift, xcode

I am looking for a way to refer to the IBOutlet variable in a custom class UIView, from another class. I found `layoutSubviews`, but each change only works on the first call, and not on each subsequent call. Thanks for help!

```
ViewController class:

var SB = StatusBar()
SB.update(1)
SB.update(2)
SB.update(3)

StatusBar class:
class StatusBar: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
     
    var ActualStatus: Int!

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: coder)
        xibSetup()
       
    
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
     
    }
     

    func update(status) {
        ActualStatus = status
        self.layoutSubviews()
    }

 
    override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
 
        label.text = ActualStatus

    }


    func xibSetup() {
        
        
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth, UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        
        
    }
    
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of:self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "StatusBar", bundle: bundle)
        
   
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

Result: label.text is 1, change only works on the first call

Comment: why you not add ```label.text = ActualStatus``` it inside the ```update``` funcation?

Comment: Because then nothing changes.

Comment: And where you declare UILabel? Add missing code.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. code updated.

Comment: share your viewController class, i think it because you create a new instance of StatusBar rather than use that already showed in your view

Comment: IBOutlets are connected in Interface Builder. `StatusBar()` is a new instance which has nothing to do with the instance in the storyboard, therefore the outlets are not connected.

Comment: Oh yes. I wanted to refer to an instance that was called in yet another controller. So how do you refer to an instance created in another controller?

Comment: The question is whether I am going the right way. If I want to have one status bar in many controllers, how to update data in one place?

Comment: I would like to update the data in one custom UIVIEW class and in all views where the custom UIVIEW class was used, the changes were visible immediately.